# Using Cappuccino JS framework with PHP backend

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, frameworks, cappuccino

I have php based application currently written using CI. I want to integrate Cappuccino JS framework at my UI layer. Does anyone know how can one go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

Cappuccino is a JS framework that brings UI developerment style much like the one you'd have with Apple's Cocoa to the web. So instead of creating HTML pages and then using a templating system to inject variables, the UI is generated purely by Obj-J and Cappuccino (which is pretty cool). Since the UI is coded completely in Obj-J it would be best if calls to the backend were done via ajax (with JSON transport). This can be done the normal way AJAX/JSON is done in javascript since Obj-J is a superset of Javascript. You can find some tutorials about Cappuccino [here](http://cappuccino.org/learn/tutorials/).

Mind you Cappuccino isn't for the light hearted. Unless you know *WHY* you're using it, you probably shouldn't be.

Comment: To use this in CodeIgniter you would use it in much they way you would use jQuery in CI?

Comment: @Kieran Yes, but even more so. Because in Cappuccino you want to completely avoid page reloads, and only do soft page loads. So everything must be JSON/XML interfaced instead of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a short example of using JSON and cappuccino here:

http://www.nice-panorama.com/Programmation/cappuccino/Tutorial-Login-Step1.html